# Force evaluation to static value of variable passed to aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing some calculations inside a function I'll use for many ggplot plots, so I need to be able to do some annotation using the results of that calculation and then pass the ggplot object back to the global environment.

```
library(ggplot2)

textDf<- data.frame(x=3,mytext="HELLO WORLD")

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + geom_point()

annotate_it <- function(g, textDf) {
  yLimMax <- layer_scales(g)$y$range$range[2]
  yAnnotate <- yLimMax / 2 #calculations are more complicated in the real use case
  g<-g+  geom_text(data=textDf,aes(x=x,y=yAnnotate, label = mytext) )
  return (g)
}

g<- annotate_it(g,textDf)
g
```

This results in the error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'yAnnotate' not found` because yAnnotate was local to the function.

Is there some way to turn yAnnotate, as used in geom_text into a static (is that the right term?) value?

If there is, in this case it will yield the plot below[image: plot I want]

Comment: Have you tried using it outside `aes()`? Like `geom_text(data = textDf, aes(x = x, label = mytext), y = yAnnotate)`... Otherwise you would have to add this variable as a column to `textDf` to make it work inside `aes()`.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems like a good workaround for this.

```
  g <- g + geom_text(data=textDf, aes(x=x, y = 0, label = mytext),
                                               nudge_y = yAnnotate)
```

**EDIT**

When the environment of the `ggplot` object is changed to the function environment, it seems to take the local object in the `aes`.

```
annotate_it <- function(g, textDf) {

  g$plot_env <- environment()

  yLimMax <- layer_scales(g)$y$range$range[2];
  yAnnotate <- yLimMax / 2; 
  g <- g + geom_text(data = textDf, 
                      aes(x = x, label = mytext, y = yAnnotate))
  return (g)
}
```

Comment: can you please also explain how `yAnnotate` is _static ?_ inside `geom_text()` and not when used inside `aes(...)` ?

Comment: That works, thanks! But the answer provided in the comment of @tino on the question is more straightforward and very slightly simpler.

Comment: @AlexHolcombe it is. I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: @parth it seems to relate what the `ggplot` object takes its environment to be.

Comment: @AlexHolcombe I think I have found why it didn't work within `aes`.